# The payload from my subscription doesn't show up in Nifi flow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-nifi, subscription

After I sent a message to my GCP subscription, it takes a minute or two (should be instant) to appear in my Nifi flow. At this point, I see a bunch of XML and my payload isn't there. Does anyone know what's possibly happening?

Comment: Please provide more detail, such as the flow definition, configuration values for the relevant processors, an example of "a bunch of XML" in the flowfile content, and the expected payload value.

Answer (score 0):

If your push messages are not acknowledged then it may [slow down delivery](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/troubleshooting#messages) of the rest significantly.

Your use case looks more like the endpoints don't acknowledge it's delivery instantly (or acknowledgement is late due to some other reasons). If the message is not acknowledged immediately then a system [will retry to deliveer](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#quotas_limits_and_delivery_rate) it (with some delay) and it will keep trying untill it's acknowledged.

Also look at the [Message Flow Control](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#config) documentation which albo may point you to a solution.

[Similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42956435/12257250) was also discussed here in StackOverflow (which might help you).